# MySql wish to discard results from left join

Tags: mysql

I got this tables:

Users

```
|id |Name  | country|
--------------
|1  | Ben   | Japan  |
|2  | Jo    | Japan  |
|3  | Sam   |   US   |
```

Mails

```
|id | subject|
--------------
|1  | Good   |
|2  | Bonus  |
```

Ref_Users_Mails

```
|user_id | mail_id|
-------------------
|   1    |    1   |
|   1    |    2   |
|   2    |    1   |
|   3    |    1   |
```

and i want the following result:
get all the users
from set of countries
not from set of countries
received the mails with this mailIds
and haven't received the mails with other mailIds

for example:
all the users from japan and not US
which got mails 1 and haven't received 2.

==> the result should be only 'Jo' but i managed to get 'Jo' and 'Ben' (because 'Ben' also got mail Id 1)

how can i filter 'Ben' out, because he got mail Id 2 also?

this is my query:

```
   SELECT * FROM Users
   LEFT JOIN Ref_Users_Mails
   ON Users.id = Ref_Users_Mails.user_id
   WHERE ( trim(Users.country) IN ( 'Japan' ) ) 
   AND ( trim(Users.country) NOT IN ( 'US' ) ) 
   AND ( trim(Ref_Users_Mails.mail_id) NOT IN ( 2 ) ) 
   ORDER BY Users.user_id;
```

Result:

```
|id |Name  | country|
--------------
|1  | Ben   | Japan  |
|2  | Jo    | Japan  |
```

Wanted result:

```
|id |Name  | country|
--------------
|2  | Jo    | Japan  |
```

Comment: *all the users from japan and not US* - does it not equal to **all the users from japan**?

Comment: This renders as an INNER JOIN

Comment: I don't think the data set is adequate to be properly representative of the problem, and the explanation is not at all clear. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @splash58  you are right, my mind with the exclude was when there is no include country.
i'll fix it.

Comment: And don't store 'untrimmed' data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rows from Users that have country = 'Japan', this is sufficient:

```
   SELECT u.id
        , u.name
        , u.country
     FROM Users u
    WHERE TRIM(u.country) IN ('Japan')  
    ORDER BY u.id
```

There's no need to add another predicate on u.country. This isn't necessary:

```
      AND TRIM(u.country) NOT IN ('US')
```

because we are guaranteed that is true if the condition in the WHERE clause is true.

From the set returned by that query, we only want users that have received mail 1. If we are guaranteed that the `(user_id,mail_id)` tuple is UNIQUE in `Ref_Users_Mails`, we can use a join operation to get that.

```
     JOIN Ref_Users_Mails r
       ON r.user_id = u.id
      AND r.mail_id = 1
```

And if we also want to *exclude* users that have received mail 2, we can use an anti-join pattern.

```
     LEFT
     JOIN Ref_Users_Mails q
       ON q.user_id = u.id
      AND q.mail_id = 2
    WHERE q.user_id IS NULL
```

So, putting that all together:

```
   SELECT u.id
        , u.name
        , u.country
     FROM Users u
     JOIN Ref_Users_Mails r
       ON r.user_id = u.id
      AND r.mail_id = 1
     LEFT
     JOIN Ref_Users_Mails q
       ON q.user_id = u.id
      AND q.mail_id = 2
    WHERE q.id IS NULL 
      AND TRIM(u.country) IN ('Japan')  
    ORDER BY u.id
```

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. For example, we could use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS predicates.

```
   SELECT u.id
        , u.name
        , u.country
     FROM Users u
    WHERE TRIM(u.country) IN ('Japan')
      AND EXISTS 
          ( SELECT 1 
              FROM Ref_Users_Mails r
             WHERE r.user_id = u.id
               AND r.mail_id = 1
          )
      AND NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT 1
              FROM Ref_Users_Mails q
             WHERE q.user_id = u.id
               AND q.mail_id = 2
          )
    ORDER BY u.id
```

This query pattern will work if we *don't* have a guarantee that the `(user_id, mail_id)` tuple is UNIQUE in Ref_Users_Mails

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, did the trick and i've learned a lot!

Comment: @user2212726: the *anti-join* pattern is a useful tool to have in the SQL toolbelt, for those situations where you need it.  The anti-join is an outer join to return all rows, including rows that have "matches", and rows that don't find a match, and then a predicate in the WHERE clause that excludes the rows that had "matches", so it returns only rows that didn't find a match.